# What storage options are available for using PlayReady on Azure Media Services?

Tags: storage, azure-media-services

My company runs a web service for film and tv production/distribution companies, and we already have a large catalog of video online. We are interested in using PlayReady with Azure Media Services and the JW Player to better protect the content we stream to our customers.

Every guide I can find demonstrates only how to stream content that has been uploaded to Azure. Is it possible to take advantage of PlayReady streaming without moving all of our stored files into Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage options = Azure Blob Storage only at this time. Based on [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started/#create-a-media-services-account-using-portal) it appears you have to back your storage with Azure Blob Storage. The creation dialog forces you to choose an existing storage account or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, please take a look at my blog: http://mingfeiy.com/integrate-azure-playready-license-service-encryptorstreaming-server. You could be able to use PlayReady services alone without using Azure Streaming service. If you have any questions, feel free to reach out to me at yanmf@microsoft.com.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan